# Tomcat 10 throws FileNotFoundException error when trying to load a resource from the classpath inside a ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat10

I want to share an issue that started to happen after upgrading from Java 8, Tomcat 8, and Spring Boot 2 to Java 17, Tomcat 10, and Spring Boot 3.

The issue is that now we can no longer load some font files from the classpath.

We have a `fonts` folder inside `src/main/resources`. When we compile the project, the folder is copied to `WEB-INF/classes`, which is the correct folder for Tomcat.

Looking at the Tomcat [Migration Guides](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration.html) I could not see anything specific to the resources change that would explain this.

The deployment is done like the old days: we compile the project to a `.war` file and then save it to the Tomcat `webapps` folder. So, inside that folder, we have the `WEB-INF/classes` folder, which contains all the app resources that will be loaded to the classpath, including the `fonts` folder.

To load the resources, we use Spring's `ResouceLoader`. Example:

`String fontPath = resourceLoader.getResource(“classpath:fonts/font.ttf”).getFile().getPath();`

The ResouceLoader is provided by Spring through dependency injection:

`private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;`

So, that was working fine before the update. So, I have looked at Tomcat 10 docs to see if the way we place the resources has changed, and it seems it remains the same; that is, files under `WEB-INF/classes` should be available. Per the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/class-loader-howto.html):

`WebappX — A class loader is created for each web application that is deployed in a single Tomcat instance. All unpacked classes and resources in the /WEB-INF/classes directory of your web application… are made visible to this web application…`

I created one sample application to demonstrate the issue: [tomcat10-test](https://github.com/rutsatz/tomcat10-test)

Inside it, we have the class [AppStartupRunner](https://github.com/rutsatz/tomcat10-test/blob/main/src/main/java/com/test/tomcat/AppStartupRunner.java) that demonstrates the issue.

On line 16 we implement the `ApplicationRunner` interface, so this code will run during startup.
On line 28, we declare a `Runnable`, that tries to load the resource:

```
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            try {
                String fontPath = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:fonts/font.ttf").getFile().getPath();
                logger.info("fontPath: {}", fontPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("error load font thread", e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
```

On line 40 we run it using a `Thread`:

```
new Thread(runnable).start(); // this works
```

On line 44 we run it using `ExecutorService`:

```
executorService.submit(runnable).get(); // this works
```

On line 51 we run it using `ForkJoinPool`:

```
THREAD_POOL.submit(runnable).get(); // Throws FileNotFoundException exception when running with Tomcat
```

If I run this code directly from my IDE, it works.
If I generate the `.war` file, through the command:
`./gradlew clean build -x test`
and then deploy the file to Tomcat 10, it does not work.

So to summarize:

1. It was working with Java 8, Tomcat 8, and Spring Boot 2.
2. It no longer works after updating to Java 17, Tomcat 10, and Spring Boot 3.
3. The error only happens when trying to load a resource from `Thread` inside `ForkJoinPool` and when running with Tomcat.

So, I do not know what changed that now Tomcat is no longer able to load resources from `classpath` when running a Thread from a `ForkJoinPool`.

I have tried to use some different approaches to load the resources:
Use the Spring's `ResourceUtils` class and also use `getClass().getClassLoader()`, but I get the same issue.

The expected result is to be able to load a `classpath` resource when an application is deployed to Tomcat 10 and the Thread is running inside a `ForkJoinPool`.

Comment: Why do you need the font path? Why not just retrieve it as a stream?

Comment: We are using a third-party library, and it does not accept inputStream. But the issue is not with getting the Path; the problem is that the resources are not found. So, if I use a stream, I get the same error because the file was not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you try without explicitly declaring the runnable variable. Since the font loading logic is self-contained in lambda function, we can simply pass it directly to the threads like this:

```
@Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {

        try {

            String fontPath = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:fonts/font.ttf").getFile().getPath();
            logger.info("fontPath: {}", fontPath);

            logger.info("---> Load font using thread");
            new Thread(() -> loadFont(fontPath)).start();

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            logger.info("---> Load font using executor service");
            executorService.submit(() -> loadFont(fontPath));

            logger.info("---> Load font using fork join pool");
            THREAD_POOL.submit(() -> loadFont(fontPath));

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error loading font", e);
        } finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
            THREAD_POOL.shutdown();
        }

    }

    private void loadFont(String fontPath) {
        try {
            logger.info("Loading font: {}", fontPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error loading font", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is an alternative. I ended up switching to ExecutorService. But my main point was that it took me a few days to discover that the problem only occurred in ForkJoinPool and only within Tomcat. So, this made me wonder if this might be a new bug introduced in the new Tomcat? Therefore, I preferred to move away from ForkJoinPool.

Comment: Just thoughs according tomcat 10 doc, Tomcat 10 uses a different class loader than earlier versions, Tomcat 10 uses a Shared Class Loader for shared classes and libraries, while the Web App Class Loader handles application-specific classes. This change affects how resources within the WAR file are accessed.

Comment: When you call getFile() on the resource in runnable and then submit it to the ForkJoinPool, the thread might be using the Web App Class Loader, which may not have access to the fonts/font.ttf resource. In Tomcat 8, a single class loader likely served both shared and app-specific classes, granting access to the resource regardless of the thread.